# View Caching in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js, sails-redis

I've got a highly trafficed website and I'm using Sails for a specific conponent on a page. However the information doesn't change that often, maybe once per day. I'm wondering if there is a way to do view caching? Ideally using a key/store like Redis?

Comment: trying for an answer myself. I think it might be no. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/owzRB5Uykhc

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app behind a proper webserver like NGINX or Apache and set them up to cache.